# Sign of eigenvectors change depending on specification of the symmetric argument for symmetric matrices

Tags: r

The signs of the eigenvectors in the `eigen` function change depending on the specification of the `symmetric` argument.  Consider the following example:

```
set.seed(1234)
data <- matrix(rnorm(200),nrow=100)
cov.matrix <- cov(data)
vectors.1 <- eigen(cov.matrix,symmetric=TRUE)$vectors
vectors.2 <- eigen(cov.matrix,symmetric=FALSE)$vectors
#The second and third eigenvectors have opposite sign
all(vectors.1 == vectors.2)
FALSE
```

This also has implications for principal component analysis as the `princomp` function appears to calculate the eigenvectors for the covariance matrix using the `eigen` function with `symmetric` set to `TRUE`.

```
pca <- princomp(data)
#princomp uses vectors.1
pca$loadings
Loadings:
       Comp.1 Comp.2
 [1,] -0.366 -0.931
 [2,]  0.931 -0.366

               Comp.1 Comp.2
SS loadings       1.0    1.0
Proportion Var    0.5    0.5
Cumulative Var    0.5    1.0
vectors.1
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.3659208 -0.9306460
[2,]  0.9306460 -0.3659208
```

Can someone please explain the source or reasoning behind the discrepancy?

Comment: The signs of the eigenvectors are arbitrary. You can flip them without changing the meaning of ther result; only their direction matters.

Comment: "princomp function appears to calculate the eigenvectors for the covariance matrix using the eigen function with symmetric set to TRUE." Not that it matters much, but your statement here is correct. Look at `methods(princomp)` then `getAnywhere(princomp.default)` and we observe `edc <- eigen(cv, symmetric = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linear algebra libraries like [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK) contain multiple subroutines for carrying out operations like eigendecompositions. The particular subroutine used in any given case may depend on the type of matrix being decomposed, and the pieces of that decomposition needed by the user.

As you can see in this snippet from `eigen`'s code, it  dispatches different LAPACK subroutines depending on whether `symmetric=TRUE` or `symmetric=FALSE` (and also, on whether the matrix is real or complex).

```
if (symmetric) {
    z <- if (!complex.x) 
        .Internal(La_rs(x, only.values))
    else .Internal(La_rs_cmplx(x, only.values))
    ord <- rev(seq_along(z$values))
}
else {
    z <- if (!complex.x) 
        .Internal(La_rg(x, only.values))
    else .Internal(La_rg_cmplx(x, only.values))
    ord <- sort.list(Mod(z$values), decreasing = TRUE)
}
```

Based on pointers in `?eigen`, `La_rs()` (used when `symmetric=TRUE`) appears to refer to [dsyevr](http://linux.die.net/man/l/dsyevr) while `La_rg()` refers to [dgeev](http://linux.die.net/man/l/dgeev).

To learn **exactly** why those two algorithms switch some of the signs of the eigenvectors of the matrix you've handed to `eigen()`, you'd have to dig into the FORTRAN code used to implement them. (Since, as others have noted, the sign is irrelevant, I'm guessing you won't want to dig quite that deep ;).

Comment: (A tiny typo: it's dsyevr not dseyvr)

Answer (score 5):

Eigenvectors remain eigenvectors after multiplication by a scalar (including -1).

The proof is simple:

If `v` is an eigenvector of matrix `A` with matching eigenvalue `c`, then by definition `Av=cv`.

Then, `A(-v) = -(Av) = -(cv) = c(-v)`. So `-v` is also an eigenvector with the same eigenvalue.

The bottom line is that this does not matter and does not change anything.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that this was just a transformation, but I was just wondering why the two methods yielded different results.

Comment: @chandler it just depends on the specifics of the method used for finding the eigenvectors. Real symmetric matrices have special mathematical properties that allow them to be solved using specialized algorithms. In general, methods for eigen decomposition tend to be iterative numerical algorithms, so the solution would be a result of the specifics of the how algorithm and how it is initialized.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the sign of eigenvector elements, then simply ensure $\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{e}>1$.  In other words, sum all the elements in each eigenvector, and ensure the sum is greater than one.  If not, change the sign of each element to the opposite sign.  This is the trick to get the sign of eigenvector elements, principal components, and loadings in PCA to come out the same as most statistical software.

Comment: wrong. This doesnt work.