# Using Eigen's SelfAdjointEigenSolver to get get the EigenVectors of a covariance matrix doesn't output expected values

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvector, covariance-matrix

I'm having trouble getting the proper eigenvectors from a covariance matrix.  Every other tool I've tried (Hipparchus, numpy, and Wolfram Alpha) all have the same results.  Note that the bolded values in the two tables below are the ones that don't match. The values are correct, but the signs are flipped.  **How can I get Eigen to return values that match the other tools?**

#### Expected (Java Hipparchus, numpy, wolfram alpha):

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.822 | -0.5666 | 0.043 | 0.0214 | -0.01286 | 0.00185 |
| -0.5082 | -0.6991 | 0.5027 | -0.0098 | -0.0102 | 0.0103 |
| **-0.2542** | **-0.4359** | **-0.8631** | **-0.0065** | **-0.0051** | **-0.02089** |
| **0.0233** | **-0.01** | 0.0018 | **-0.882** | **0.47043** | **0.00655** |
| -0.000089 | -0.0023 | **0.0228** | **0.102117** | **0.20486** | **-0.97318** |
| 0.00802 | 0.0134 | 0.00495 | -0.4593 | -0.85813 | -0.2287 |

#### Received (Eigen C++):

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.822 | -0.5666 | 0.043 | 0.0214 | -0.01286 | 0.00185 |
| -0.5082 | -0.6991 | 0.5027 | -0.0098 | -0.0102 | 0.0103 |
| **0.254237** | **0.435874** | **0.86306** | **0.006458** | **0.005145** | **0.02089** |
| **-0.023292** | **0.010035** | 0.001800 | **0.882024** | **-0.470473** | **-0.006552** |
| -0.000089 | -0.0023 | **-0.022781** | **-0.102117** | **-0.204863** | **0.97318** |
| 0.00802 | 0.0134 | 0.00495 | -0.4593 | -0.85813 | -0.2287 |

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
...
Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6> covariance_matrix;
covariance_matrix <<
    11918156.569, -2503013.667, -132100.597, 294232.999, -89836.267, 13818.007,
    -2503013.667, 9953136.379, -660701.613, -85984.752, 177042.329, -10946.126,
    -132100.597, -660701.613, 7553635.065, 10310.484, -20116.259, 174844.429,
    294232.999, -85984.752, 10310.484, 36006.817, -10978.320, -41.400,
    -89836.267, 177042.329, -20116.259, -10978.320, 20835.413, -1528.193,
    13818.007, -10946.126, 174844.429, -41.400, -1528.193, 22188.775;

Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6>> eigen_solver(covariance_matrix);
Eigen::Vector<double, 6> eigenvalues = eigen_solver.eigenvalues().reverse(); // values are OK
Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6> eigenvectors = eigen_solver.eigenvectors().transpose().colwise().reverse();
std::cout << "eigenvectors:\n" << eigenvectors.matrix() << "\n";
```

Comment: You provided `covariance_matrix` but then perform the eigensolution on `fme`.  I assume you did something in between.

Comment: that was a typo.  they are the same thing.  I fixed it.

Comment: The sign is arbitrary. When I try to reproduce it with numpy, I get an entirely different set of signs. See for example here for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998228/sign-of-eigenvectors-change-depending-on-specification-of-the-symmetric-argument

Comment: Your numpy, wolfram, etc table doesn't match what I get when I use those same tools. 
 Your Eigen table does match (as a transposed scalar multiple) of numpy.linalg.eigh, matlab, wolfram and numpy.linalg.eig.